# Java Soap WSDL extended objects

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

I am trying to make a web service that returns a list of Reports.  My problem is that reports is my parent class and there are several children reports like MonthlySalesReport and AnnualSalesReport.  Both MonthlySalesReport and AnnualSalesReport extend Reports.  However my wsdl does not describe these objects.  It just shows the methods that Reports has.  Is there a way to get my wsdl to show all of the children objects?

Comment: Provide some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: @XmlSeeAlso({MonthlySalesReport.class,AnnualSalesReport.class})